# "Makefile circular dependency dropped" error

Tags: makefile

I'm getting a makefile error when trying to run **make client** or **make server**. I've poked around looking for why this is, but I can't figure it out. Here's my makefile:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -std=c++11 -Wno-write-strings
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES= UDP_Client.cpp UDP_Server.cpp
CSOURCES = cmain.cpp UDP_Client.cpp
SSOURCES = smain.cpp UDP_Server.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
COBJECTS=$(CSOURCES:.cpp=.o)
SOBJECTS=$(SSOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=run
CEXECUTABLE=client
SEXECUTABLE=server


all:
    @echo "Please specifiy client or server"

client: $(CSOURCES) $(CEXECUTABLE)

server: $(SSOURCES) $(SEXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

$(CEXECUTABLE): $(COBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(COBJECTS) -o $@

$(SEXECUTABLE): $(SOBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(SOBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm *.o
```

And the errors I'm getting seem simple, but here's their actual text:

```
make: Circular client <- client dependency dropped.
```

Answer (score 1):

You've told make that `client` depends on `client` (after `$(CEXECUTABLE)` is expanded), this is clearly wrong.

Your makefile is a little confusing but what I *think* you're trying to do is

```
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 -Wno-write-strings
cobjs := cmain.o UDP_Client.o
sobjs := smain.o UDP_Server.o

.PHONY: clean

client: $(cobjs)
server: $(sobjs)
client server:
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
clean:
    $(RM) $(cobjs) $(sobjs)
```

You don't need most of the rules and variables you've defined, make already knows how to compile stuff. In fact if you rename `cmain.cpp` to `client.cpp` and `smain.o` to `server.cpp` (and change the name of the `.o` files in the makefile accordingly), you won't even need the recipe for `client` and `server`.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `run`, is it a different executable? If so how can it depend on `UDP_Client.o` and `UDP_Server.o`, as presumably neither have a `main` function defined?